# getting kCFURLVolumeIsAutomountedKey missing when trying to play an MP3 file with Java FX

Tags: java, macos, javafx-2

I am trying to use Java FX to play an MP3 file, but I keep getting the following error:

kCFURLVolumeIsAutomountedKey missing for file://localhost/private/var/setup/: The file “setup” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

I have checked through my computer and shown hidden files but cannot find the localhost folder.

Here is the output for the version of Java I am running:

java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)
rover-226-42:MP3Player ajgoddu$

I am on a Mac with OSX Sierra, here is the code I am running:

```
    import java.net.URL;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.media.Media;
    import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class MP3 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Media media = new Media( "file:///Users/ajgoddu/Desktop/Projects/Java/MediaPlayer/MP3Player/test.mp3" );
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.play();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Audio Player 1");
    primaryStage.setWidth(200);
    primaryStage.setHeight(200);
    primaryStage.show();
    }
  }
```

Anybody know what exactly this error means and why it could be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might need to download the XCode CLI Tools per this [slightly unrelated Github issue](https://github.com/mikaelbr/gulp-notify/issues/113).

Question from link:

> I'm running macOS Sierra V10.12, just updated today. Getting this error message upon running Gulp task:
>   `[12:56:04] gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify' Message: 2016-09-21 12:56:04.205 terminal-notifier[11630:142879] kCFURLVolumeIsAutomountedKey missing for file:///private/var/setup/: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “setup” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///private/var/setup/, NSFilePath=/private/var/setup, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ffe4d632930 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}`

Answer:

> I was also having this issue, and after installing the Xcode CLI tools
>   via `xcode-select --install` and restarting my machine I stopped
>   receiving the error. It may have just been the restart that sorted it,
>   as installing the CLI tools alone didn't solve the problem.

Unfortunately I'm on a Windows machine at work and can't try this with my Mac at home. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @AustenGoddu Great - glad to hear it! Please consider accepting the answer as correct if you think it was sufficiently helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new here